# How to use TerminableMiddleware in Laravel 5 correctly?

Tags: laravel, php

I'm experimenting with TerminableMiddleware in Laravel 5, to try and understand it and see what can be achieved, once the HTTP request has been answered. My thinking is that it was something like :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php

Though I put together a test here, and I can see the request is held open till the Terminable has finished. My thinking is that it would of sent the response and closed the connection. Or does it rely on fastcgi_finish_request() being installed ?

Am I trying to use it in the wrong way ?

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\TerminableMiddleware;

    use Closure;

    class MyTestMiddleware implements TerminableMiddleware {


    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $response->setContent("OK " . time());

        return $response;
    }

    public function terminate($request, $response)
    {

        $fp = fopen('/tmp/deleteme', "w");

        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000 ; $i++)
        {
           fputs($fp, $this->generateRandomString(400) . "\n");
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function generateRandomString($length = 10)
    {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
        {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The terminate() method is called in the end of your public/index.php file:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

The $response object is an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, which current implementation of send() method is:

```
public function send()
{
    $this->sendHeaders();
    $this->sendContent();

    if (function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
        fastcgi_finish_request();
    } elseif ('cli' !== PHP_SAPI) {
        static::closeOutputBuffers(0, true);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

So the answer is Yes, it relies on fastcgi_finish_request being installed. In fact, it tries to call it if exists. If not, it'll just output your response content and run the terminate() method while the connection is open.

If you need to do something heavier after the connection is closed, you should implement it using Laravel's [Queues](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events) instead.